# Help in identifing these 2 materials

Tags: capacitor, pcb-assembly, enclosure, insulation, materials

i would like to know if anyone of you recognize these 2 materials and what they are used for ?

1. A material sticky on one side normal on the other , used between capacitors and aluminum enclosure .

[image: capacitors interface material]

2. A material consisting of 2 parts face is like card board and second part is like thick butter paper. IT is used between 2 pcbs stacked over each other .

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Dielectrics of all kinds. You should look on 3M website. Or laird technologies

Comment: thanks , but what is so special about them , is the first one thermally conductive ?? is there a general recommandation that you should use x-type of material between y and z etc...

Comment: I guess they are not conductive, convenient for assembly, have specific part number, etc. The application seems quite obvious- vibration suppression and isolation. But who knows?

Comment: Is it a part from jerky object (like vehicles)? The first-one (Capacitor-touching) seems to tightening the board (locking the  space throughwhich the board can vibrate or dangle). As well the aluminium cn of the e-caps electrically connected to the inner content of capacitor (I've checked it with multimeter by putting one  probe at one leg and other-probe on the open portion of capacitor-top). So , in a jerky device, there maybe need to keep an insulator between capacitors-open metallic surface and your gadget's chassis.

Comment: @ always confused , Woww thanks that seems very true , yes the board is made for automotive enviroment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both materials are there to prevent undesired electrical contact.

Electrolytic caps often have an exposed metallic can container which is electrically connected to one terminal of the capacitor. Having that can touch the aluminum enclosure would be an undesired short to ground.

The two PCBs may have some metallic projections (leads from components on these boards) which could come into contact due to vibration or pressure, so the "butter paper" ensures no inadvertent short can occur.

Answer (score 3):

They're structural, and not electrically or thermally conductive.

The first one is for sticking the capacitor onto the board (likely for assembly or structural reasons).

The second one is just an insulative layer, probably to prevent the 2 boards from shorting out (they have the solder sides facing each other) if they should be bent or ve in a high-vibration environment (or potentially to allow cheaper and smaller mounting to the chassis without compromising electrical properties).